# What would be a good video editing computer?

Tags: recommendation

Would a late (2013), retina display, 16 GB RAM, 256 GB HD, 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5, MacBook Pro be suitable for editing video?

Comment: Can you add a bit more info on what you will be editing, ie: music videos, short films, weddings etc, what NLE are you going to be using FCPX, PremierPro, Avid, etc, the more info you can provide the better we can answer the question which at this point is very vague

Comment: Suitable yes, ofcourse. Would change HD to SSD, makes your workflow much faster.
But like Adam said, be more specific to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes! Unless by videos you mean "hollywood style" movies. Then the answer is no.

Comment: A lot of "hollywood style" movies have been made on machines less powerfull than that. For editing you don't need a supercomputer, it's only when you start doing CGI and SFX that you really need high end specs. But you do want lots of fast storage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's powerful enough, even to edit features ... as long as:

- you use low-resolution proxies (copies) for long projects.
- you edit from an external drive with USB3 or better and not from your computer's HDD (avoid stuffing your HDD with large data files anyway).